# Phpspec matching fails with stdClass Object

Tags: laravel, phpspec

Working with a laravel 5 app and have a problem with phpspec. Why does my Phpspec unit test below fail or more precisely how can I get the stdClass Object keys to match so that it wouldn't fail?

**My spec file:**

```
function it_checks_add_starting_date_to_flow()

    {      
    $dealflows = new \stdClass ();
    this->add_starting_date_to_flow($dealflows)->shouldReturn((object)[]);

    }
```

**And my helper function that I am testing:**

```
public static function add_starting_date_to_flow($dealflows)
    {

    $dealflows= new \stdClass();
    return $dealflows;
    }
```

**From phpspec I get the following response:**

App/libraries/Mmdealhelpers
  65  - it checks add starting date to flow
      expected [obj:stdClass], but got [obj:stdClass].

```
  @@ -1,1 +1,1 @@
  -stdClass Object &000000001d025295000000007dd68060 ()
  +stdClass Object &000000001d02529a000000007dd68060 ()


    80 //                    ]
    81 //                    ));
    82                       $this->add_starting_date_to_flow($dealflows)->shouldReturn((object)[]);
    83 
    84         }
    85 


   0 vendor/phpspec/phpspec/src/PhpSpec/Matcher/IdentityMatcher.php:78
     throw new PhpSpec\Exception\Example\NotEqualException("Expected [obj:stdC...")
   1 [internal]
     spec\App\libraries\MmdealhelpersSpec->it_checks_add_starting_date_to_flow()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*shouldReturn()* calls the [identity matcher](https://github.com/phpspec/phpspec/blob/master/src/PhpSpec/Matcher/IdentityMatcher.php#L66), which uses strict comparison. Your spec is failing as the object you're expecting is not the same instance as the one that's returned from the method.

Use the [comparison matcher](https://github.com/phpspec/phpspec/blob/master/src/PhpSpec/Matcher/ComparisonMatcher.php#L57) instead. It uses weak comparison and can is invoked with *shouldBeLike()*:

```php
function it_checks_add_starting_date_to_flow()
{      
    $dealflows = new \stdClass();
    $this->add_starting_date_to_flow($dealflows)->shouldBeLike((object)[]);
}
```